# How to make an octogonal div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Pretty simple idea, but I'm not sure how to do this. I'd like to be able to style it as one `div` (if possible).

How can I create an octagonal `div`?

Comment: You can't.  Your options are faking it with an image or using SVG/VML

Comment: or css, which is exactly what im after...

Comment: The example below isn't really an octogonal div; it's a square with the corners obscured.  It's fine if you just need to display an octagon, but you need to put anything layered behind it, you're in trouble.

Comment: @SamDufel http://jsfiddle.net/uBC2X/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The CSS used in [this link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#octagon) is this:

```
#octagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

#octagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;    
    border-bottom: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid #eee;
    border-right: 29px solid #eee;
        width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}

#octagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;    
    border-top: 29px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid #eee;
    border-right: 29px solid #eee;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

It is constructed from the div element itself which is given a rectangular shape. Using the  `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes, content is added to create two trapeziums that complete the octagon. Cleverly this keeps the actual tag count at just one by using the funkier bits of CSS.

The origins of this technique can be found [here](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/slantinfo.html).

---

[Here is a quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/EXBYm/). The blue part is the `:before` CSS and the green the `:after` CSS. And even better, [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uBC2X/) that allows transparent backgrounds! (thank you @GGG).

Comment: I'd +1 for a mind-bogglingly cool link, but I'm out of votes today =/ Great find, though

Comment: Thanks for this example, I was expecting to use :before and :after. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @Joe That's quite alright; it's the thought that counts. I particularly like the Yin Yang in [my posted link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) - it's fantastically simple!

Comment: You can #link to the Yin Yang: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#yin-yang

Comment: Nice example. It's an old technique, first seen [here](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/slantinfo.html) afaik.

Comment: @thirtydot Thank you! I was wondering if I could do that. I started looking through the source for `<a name="...">` tags.

Answer (score 3):

How about just making a square, rotate it 45 degrees and then clip the corners?

```
.octagon {
    height: 10em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10em;
}

.octagon:after {
    background: red;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;


  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
       -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
          transform: rotate(45deg); 

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjzwz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also achive an octogonal div with [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) using the [polygon element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon).
Here is an example :

```css
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <polygon points="3 0, 7 0, 10 3, 10 7, 7 10, 3 10, 0 7, 0 3" />
</svg>
```